# When I am trying to access the id from params it showing undefined params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import {BrowserRouter,Routes,Route} from "react-router-dom"
import './App.css';
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Listing from "./pages/Listing";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" Component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/listing/:mealid" Component={Listing} />
    </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the main file with route paths:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Header from '../components/Home/Header';
import ListingDisplay from '../components/listing/ListingDisplay';
import Cuisinefilter from '../components/listing/Cuisinefilter';
import Costfilter from '../components/listing/Costfilter';
import Footer from '../components/Home/Footer';
import axios from "axios"
const url = "http://localhost:5000/restaurents?mealid=";

class Listing extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          restaurantlist: " ",
        };
      }


    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Header/>
                <div className="main">
                    <div className="listing">
                      <div className="filter">
                        <center>Filter</center>
                        <Cuisinefilter/>
                        <Costfilter/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <ListingDisplay/>
                </div>
                <Footer/>
            </Container>
        );
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        let mealid = this.props.match.params.mealid;
        console.log("id",mealid);
        // sessionStorage.setItem("mealid", mealid);
        // axios.get(`${url}${mealid}`, { method: "GET" }).then((res) => {
        //   this.setState({ restaurantlist: res.data });
        //   console.log(res.data);
        // });
      }
}

export default Listing;
```

When I am trying to access the mealid from the params it showing the error like
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Comment: Why not try logging the props themselves to see what is actually being passed in? Are you navigating to /listing/someMealId?